# jQuery how can I add a table row for every new div thats clicked?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to create a new `table` row for every `div` that is clicked and create the row once for every individual `div` so clicking twice on the same `div` will not create two rows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="block div1"></div>
<div class="block div2"></div>
<div>
    <table class="block table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('block').on('click', function () {
    $('table.body').append('<tr><td></td> <td></td></tr>');
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grundizer/9vnmuudy/7/)

Comment: Your example is completely broken

Comment: Please include your code (we don't need the CSS) in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as fixing the incorrect selectors, to have an event fire only once per bound target you can use the `.one()` method of jQuery instead of `.on()` like so:

```
$('.block').one('click', function () {
    $('table .body').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
});
```

This click event will then only fire a maximum of once per element to which it is bound.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vnmuudy/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block').on('click', function () {
        $('table .body').append('<tr><td></td> <td></td></tr>');
});
```

you forgot the "." at block and did "table.body" instead of "table .body"

Answer (score 0):

Going by your classes in the table you actually meant to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9vnmuudy/8/

```
$('.block').on('click', function () {
        $('.table .body').append('<tr><td></td> <td></td></tr>');
});
```